# JSON field undefined in EJS template

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, ejs

On my front-end, I have this html:

```
<a name="user" id="user" value="<%=user%>"></a>
```

I do this to be entirely sure user is defined on my front-end

And then I have a JS file with this:

```
    var user;
    var teamCollection = new TeamCollection([]);  //new Backbone collection  

    $(document).ready(function(){
        user = $("#user").attr("value"); //pull user object from html
        window.userHomeMainTableView = new UserHomeMainTableView({el: $("#user-home-main-table-div")});
        window.userHomeMainTableView.render();
    });
```

the render method of userHomeMainTableView looks like this:

```
  render: function () {
        console.log('teamCollection models:', teamCollection.models); //defined
        console.log('user:', user); // defined
        var data = {teamCollection:teamCollection,user:user}; //this should point to the user variable at the top of the JS file.
        var html = new EJS({url: '/js/backbone/views/UserHomeViews/templates/main_table_template.ejs'}).render(data);
        this.$el.html(html);
        return this;
    },
```

so, the user var is defined at the top of the JS file, but somehow when I pass the data into the EJS template, teamCollection is defined but user is not.

How can this be? Any reason why this would be?

Here is the EJS file

```
<table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Team Name</th>
            <th>Club</th>
            <th>Sport</th>
            <th>Delete?</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <%
        for(var i=0; i <teamCollection.models.length; i++) { //teamCollection IS defined :) good

        var team = teamCollection.models[i].toJSON();
           var user_id = user._id; //USER IS UNDEFINED !! :(
        %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%=i+1%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="font-big" href='/users/<%=user_id%>/teams/<%= team._id%>/teamDashboard'>
                    <%= team.sport %>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-warning" onclick=window.userHomeMainTableView.deleteTeam("<%= team._id%>");>delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: can you produce a fiddle that reproduces this error. With a global it could be being overridden somewhere else.

Comment: I hope you're not trying to access the value of `user` in document ready line `user = $("#user").attr("value"); //pull user object from html`, which you set in `render` method later on. If not, then what does console say about `user` below `user = $("#user").attr("value");` line.

Comment: the user variable is defined in the document.ready function, it is also defined in the render function, but for some reason it is not making it into the EJS template, and is undefined in the template, no idea why

Comment: @Quince i don't think it's being overwritten since user var is defined right before the EJS template compile call

Comment: also, I have to say, what I am doing seems like a security risk...getting the user info from the DOM itself...